# Lithium Base URL in Controller

Tags: php, lithium

This seems like a really simple question, but having trouble figuring out an answer.

In lithium, How do you get the base url of a site from within the controller?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From within the controller...

```
$this->request->env('base');
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew there had to be some simple way to do it.